# .Net Core 3.0 hostfxr.dll could not be found

Tags: wpf, .net-core

using .net core 3.0 and wpf

I have successfully built an app in wpf for .net core 3.0 and it runs fine where i have installed visual studio (dev environment).

However as soon as i copy the release folder and run it on another computer i get hostfxr.dll could not be found
if this is a framework-dependant application, install run time in global location C:\program files\dotnet or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the run time location

I have already installed the 3.0 preview run time and it matches the location and set the DOTNET_ROOT enviroment variable and pointed it to the runtime location C:\program files\dotnet

anything missing?

Comment: Check .net framework (NOT .net core though) on the target machine, perhaps? It is really a wild guess.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so you have to install the sdk as well as the run-time for .net core 3.0 run time for the app to run.

don't have to set environment variable

Comment: It sort of defeats the object of having separate SDKs and Runtimes.

Answer (score 3):

You must create the environment variable called: DOTNET_ROOT and reference the installation location of .Net Core SDK

Answer (score 3):

yesterday I faced the same issue and the reason I found this link. I followed the solutions provided on this link but in my case the deployment environment was the issue. listing down the steps I followed to fix this.

1. Deploy .Net core runtime with your application if not available on target machine from
   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1
2. set the environment variable DOTNET_ROOT
3. the appropriate deployment path/environment SIT/UAT (in my case) to solve this  (a)"Deployment Mode: Self Contained" needs to be selected in Visual studio 2019. while publishing    OR
   (b) dotnet publish -c Release -r  --self-contained true
4. in case the target machine is 64 bit or 86. C:\Program Files\dotnet OR C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet